# Referencing won't work with TeXworks and Biber/BibLatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, biber, texworks

I have been trawling the internet all day to try and find a way to get the referencing on TeXworks to work.

Every time I run Biber on TeXworks, I now get this error message:

```
BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\lcold\AppData\Local\Temp\Nl6GHw4kOm\PowerRuleReferences.bib_15576.utf8, line 2, syntax error: found "author", expected ","
```

My bib file looks like this:

```
@online{Dawkins2003 ,
author = {Dawkins, Paul} ,
title = {The Definition of the Derivative} ,
year = {2003} ,
url= {http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DefnOfDerivative.aspx} ,
note = {accessed on 03 Apr 2018}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The entry you have posted works fine despite the slightly weird convention of placing a space before the comma. The error message makes me think you have forgotten a comma after the `@<type>{<entrykey>` block. Can you try and find out which entry causes the error?

Comment: Your thoughts are probably not mistaken, as that is the key info in the error message ;). Also, kindly consider adding a comma after the 'note' line. In case you want to add more info to this entry, you won't have to worry about the comma, which might give you nasty, hard to trace errors. Furthermore: reference managers like jabref, mendeley or citavi don't make mistakes like this. Consider using them :)

Comment: Any news here? Can you try and isolate which entry causes the problem? The entry shown should be fine and worked in my tests, so it must be something else.

Comment: Any news here? As mentioned in my last comment, the entry you have shown us actually works. So we can't really help you further details being absent. I'll vote to close your question as unclear what you are asking in due time if no clarifications are made.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear as the problem is not visible in the little code that is shown in the question. The question has not been updated in almost two weeks and the OP was last seen when asking the question.